# MySQL query order by date desc, ignore other records

Tags: mysql, date, select

I have a MySql table with the following data:

```
| ID | House |         Date        |
|  1 | A     | 2015-03-13 15:56:59 |
|  2 | A     | 2015-03-11 12:19:45 |
|  3 | A     | 2015-03-06 00:00:00 |
|  4 | B     | 2015-03-13 16:07:21 |
|  5 | B     | 2015-03-11 13:02:22 |
```

I'm trying to get the following results:

```
| ID | House |         Date        |
|  1 | A     | 2015-03-13 15:56:59 |
|  4 | B     | 2015-03-13 16:07:21 |
```

I've tried using subqueries and other types of things. Any ideas of what I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

```
select h1.id, h1.house, h1.date 
  from house h1 left join house h2 
    on h1.house = h2.house and h1.date < h2.date
  where h2.date is null
```

This query makes no assumptions about the ordering of the data.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2da11/1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table name is **tableName**

```
Select tbl.id, temp.house, 
temp.datecol
from tableName tbl,
(
select max(tbl2.datecol), 
tbl2.house 
from tableName tbl2 
group by tbl2.house
) temp 
where tbl.house=temp.house
order by temp.datecol asc;
```

Answer (score -3):

This can be done in a simpler way.

> SELECT id, house, date FROM house WHERE date > '2015-03-13'

Comment: yes. if you assume that an individual house will NEVER have more than one entry with a date > '2015-03-13', or that a house will NEVER have just one entry with a date < '2015-03-13'